# JSON.NET - custom enum handling at deserialization

Tags: c#, json, enums

We have a JSON that we can deserialize into a custom domain model, no problems at all. It includes a property which is a custom enum:

```
public enum UserType
{
    President,
    Chump
}
```

We've now changed our enum class but still need to *accept and deserialize* the previous values of any JSON's that arrive. It's like we now have two versions of our JSON

```
public enum UserType
{
    President,
    Vice-President,
    Citizen  // Chump maps to Citizen, now.
}
```

and in the json itself..

`"userType": "chump"; // needs to map to Citizen`

I'm not sure how to do this.

Is this using `JsonConverter` ?

Also, this is our custom settings we use for all our serialization and deserializtion. NOTE: we serialize any enum to it's `string` description/value, not it's `int` value.

```
internal static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new JsonConverter[]
    {
        new StringEnumConverter()
    },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom `Converter` deriving from `StringEnumConverter`:

```
public class UserTypeEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(UserType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, 
                                    Type objectType, 
                                    object existingValue, 
                                    JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            var isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);
            if (!isNullable)
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException();
            }
            return null;
        }

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        var value = token.ToString();
        if (string.Equals(value, "chump", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return UserType.Citizen;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }               
    }
}
```

The converter handles the case when the underlying type is nullable as well and is invoked only when the type of property declared on the deserialized class is `UserType`. It then checks if the value being parsed is the "deprecated" one and if not, it delegates the reading to the base `StringEnumConverter`.

Comment: Sweet! totally grok it :) ta!

Comment: Also, just edited it to make it a bit more readable and moved the `isNullable` _inside_ the `== JsonToken.Null` check ... why check if it's nullable or not for all those `TokenTypes` that are not `JsonToken.Null`? Waste of unused cpu (yes yes ... micro opt... etc).

Comment: Great :-) ! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 7):

In your `Enum` just add the [`EnumMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute which specify the value for serialization/deserialization process.

```
public enum UserType
{
    President,
    VicePresident,

    [EnumMember(Value = "chump")]
    Citizen  // Chump maps to Citizen, now.
}
```

The property `userType` will be `Citizen` when, in your json, the `userType` property is equal to `"Chump"` or `"Citizen"`.

Remember to add the `System.Runtime.Serialization` reference to your project.

### Edit

I noticed that the check of the `Value` property of `EnumMember` attribute is case-sensitive. So you can't use `"Chump"` if in your json you have `"chump"`. To solve this problem you can use a custom `StringEnumConverter`.

```
public class UserTypeEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var userTypeType = typeof(UserType);
        if (objectType == userTypeType)
        {
            var value = reader.Value.ToString().ToLower();

            foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(userTypeType))
            {
                var memberValue = GetEnumMemberValue(userTypeType.GetMember(item)[0]);
                if (memberValue != null && memberValue.ToLower() == value)
                {
                    return Enum.Parse(userTypeType, item);
                }
            }
        }

        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}

private static string GetEnumMemberValue(MemberInfo memberInfo)
{
    var attributes = memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), inherit: false);

    if (attributes.Length == 0) return null;

    return ((EnumMemberAttribute)attributes[0]).Value;
}
```

In the above code, I check only the `EnumMember` attribute because the `UserType`'s members case-insensitive check is already done by the default `StringEnumConvert`.

Note that this converter will work only for your `UserType` enum beacuse of the check:

```
var userTypeType = typeof(UserType);
if (objectType == userTypeType)
{
```

Replace the `JsonSerializerSettings` initialization with:

```
internal static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new JsonConverter[]
    {
        new UserTypeEnumConverter()
    },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
```

I assumed that `Vice-President` enumerator is `VicePresident` in `UserType`.

Comment: Ta for the effort - really really helps. Even going so far as to show how to use it in a `JsonSerializerSettings` class. I'm going to give the answer to @martin though because I found his `ReadJson` a tiny bit simpler to read and a bit more succinct. But I seriously do appreciated your effort and help. It _has_ helped me, though. (I can't give 2x ticks :(  )

Comment: No problem, happy that helps :)

Comment: If you run into trouble with deserialization of string enums and you suspect it is caused by the case of the value, double check that your type is actually an enum to begin with.
I just lost an hour troubleshooting why "GET" would not deserialize into a HttpMethod thinking HttpMethod was a enum.